# How to properly set the input_shape of LSTM layers?

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have an input data with the following shape:`(5395, 69, 1)`

**Should my input_shape be:**

- `(69,1)` or
- `(1,69)` ?

With 69 neurons in the LSTM layer I get in the first input_shape 19'596 parameters to train, and with the second
38'364 parameters, aren't those the result of get as input 1 and 69 values, respectively? My question is should I have as input 1 because I have 1 feature or 69 because I have 69 timesteps, and why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The input of `LSTM` layer has a shape of `(num_timesteps, num_features)`, therefore:

- If each input sample has 69 timesteps, where each timestep consists of 1 feature value, then the input shape would be `(69, 1)`.
- If each input sample is a single timestep of 69 feature values, then probably it does not make sense to use an RNN layer at all since basically the input is not a sequence. Instead, it's better to flatten the input sample (i.e. reshape `(1, 69)` to `(69,)`) and then use other connectivity architectures/layers (e.g. `Dense`).

---

As a side note, I might be wrong, but I have a feeling that you are mixing the number of input timesteps and the number of units/neurons in LSTM layer (specifically, I am referring to this sentence of yours: "With 69 neurons in the LSTM layer..."). These two have nothing to do with each other and they should not necessarily be the same number. The number of units/neurons in a LSTM layer determines the representational capability of that layer and should be set accordingly based on experiments/experience. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61149955/2099607) explains this point a bit further if you are interested.

Comment: Well explained. Due to your side note, I set the number of neurons of the LSTM layer equal to timesteps because I am working on a simple example, where I do this for faster experimentation, letting clear that this aspect need more work.

Comment: Now due to your comment in the link " Further, when the number of units is 3, it basically means that only 3 features is extracted from each input timestep, i.e. each input timestep will be represented by 3 features, and these 3 features will be fed to the next layer" Does this mean that each timestep in the sequence will have 3 features or that each sequence will have 3 features

Comment: @DavidDiaz By having 3 units in LSTM layer, each timestep would be represented as 3-value vector by that LSTM layer; however, you may decide to use the representation of all timesteps (i.e. by passing `return_sequences=True` argument to `LSTM` layer) or just the last timestep representation (i.e. `return_sequences=False` which is the default case).

Comment: I have a dude if I use a LSTM and a Dense layer as structure passing to the LSTM  ```return_sequences = T``` should I use a flatter layer? and why?

Comment: @DavidDiaz It depends on what you want to achieve (i.e. application and problem formulation). For example, if you want to predict something for **each timestep** (and not just a single prediction for the entire sequence) then it makes sense to use `return_sequences=True` and a `Dense` layer. As I said, depending on the scenario, the architecture of the model might vary.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, can you help with this questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60599127/name-of-a-custom-fuction-in-keras-model-r)

Comment: [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60609722/how-load-a-keras-model-with-custom-loss)